# Android Presentation for DualScreen

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

We make an application who use Presentation to display some views differents when device have more than one screen. I have somes difficulties because Presentation need a context, so when we change activities, i have to dismiss old presentation and create a new one with the new context. But during this laps of time, the screen show the first activity and this is not good.
I try a lot of different things, like dismiss Presentation only in the OnStop of the activity or never dismiss but i have huge memory leak everytime.

```
 private void setActivity(Activity activity)
    {
        final MyPresentation presentationTemp = presentation;

        try
        {
            presentation = new MyPresentation(activity, getDisplay(activity), activity.getLocalClassName());
            presentation.setCancelable(false);
            presentation.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            presentation.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(presentationTemp != null)
        {
            try
            {
                presentationTemp.dismiss();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I call this function in the onResume of every activities

Comment: Perhaps you should have fewer activities, using fragments or composables to represent screens.

Comment: Yes it could work but i can't do that, i have a very huge application with a lot of differents activities.